# What is the best way to deal with negative integers inputs in a python calculator?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello Fellow Developer's and Eng's:

How can I handle these two type's of input **1) when user enter "-0"** and **2) When user enter minus symbol "-"**, within my **while** loop for adding nonnegative integers.

The program developed functions in the overall design, which is to add non negative integers, but it has a flaw when a user input -0 or -(minus) sign. I want to print('you have entered a negative int or a negative/minus - symbol') when these entries are made by the user.

Currently, the program continues without adding when user submit -0 in the input and there is ValueError when user just submit - symbol.

Please provide feedback.

```
entry = 0 
sum = 0
# Request input from the user
print('This is nonnegative integer addition program. \n',)

while entry >= 0:
    entry=int(input('Please enter numbers to add: '))
    if entry >=0:
        sum+=entry
    elif entry<0 or str(entry[0])=='-' or str(entry)=='-0':  # -0 nor (first index -(minus) does not work
        print('You have entered a negative integer or symbol:', \
            entry, ', therefore you have been exited out of the program')
print('total integer input sum =',sum)
```

Comment: You can fix this question by leaving out a bunch of the forward, about what you read, that this question is interesting. etc etc. And say why it doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to check the inputed string for `"-0"` before you convert it to an integer and treat it normally.

Comment: Thanks Matt, post desc updated.

Comment: Why you need to separate `'-'` and `'-0'`? Both fall under the condition of `entry[0] == '-'`... If you find yourself getting into too much conditions trying to parse the string, you might consider using regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer. You convert your value to an int and you can no longer access the characters. I've made the program store the user_input and check that.

```
entry = 0 
sum = 0
# Request input from the user
print('This is nonnegative integer addition program. \n',)

while entry >= 0:
    user_input = input('Please enter numbers to add: ')

    if '-' in user_input:
        print( 
           'You have entered a negative integer or symbol:', 
           user_input, 
           ', therefore you have been exited out of the program'
        )
        break

    entry = int(user_input)
    sum+=entry

print('total integer input sum =',sum)
```

In this version I store the input string as `user_input` and check it for a '-' symbol. I use `'-' in` instead of `user_input[0]=='-'` because input that starts with a space can still work with `int`.

Another thing to note, your if/elif was over specified.

```
if entry >=0:
    sum+=entry
elif entry<0 or str(entry[0])=='-' or str(entry)=='-0':
    break
```

In your second clause entry is guaranteed to be less than zero. So the `str(entry[0])` never gets called. Thankfully because it was an error. Your if statement is equivalent to.

```
if entry>=0:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Lastly a small point. When you have a set of brackets like in your print statment. You don't need a `\` to indicate a line continuation.

```
print(
    "one",
    "two"
)
```

Python recognizes the open `(`. If you wanted to continue a string you would need it.

```
print("one \
      two")
```

Comment: Hello Matt, Thank you so much for the feedback and being involved in this post. I added a third elif, following the if '-' in ri: but printing a message, but no avail in handling the error/input. I am thinking of nesting the conditional statements further and creating a third variable to hold the -0 or the minus sign to manage it that way.

Comment: @ASEDev I've updated the answer, I used your original code and I've added a couple notes about what you've done in the program.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I definitely have a better understanding on my program and its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing the input as int `entry=int(input('Please enter numbers to add: '))` the entry value is 0 because on int the is no -0 so if you want to check if the user input -0 you need to keep it as str.
You can try

```
entry = 0 
sum = 0
print('This is nonnegative integer addition program. \n',)

while int(entry) >= 0:
    entry=input('Please enter numbers to add: ')
    if entry[0] !='-':
        if int(entry) >= 0:
            sum+=int(entry)
    elif entry[0]=='-' or entry=='-0':
        print('You have entered a negative integer or symbol:', \
            entry, ', therefore you have been exited out of the program')
        entry = -1
    print('total integer input sum =',sum)
```

Comment: Hello Mr.Arad, Thanks for the feedback, however, if you try your code and my code, the program still accepts -0 and outputs value error on - minus symbol input. I will answer this post once I find a solution to this but I will continue my learning on loops. This is a cool pothole to be aware of though and being capable of handling/fixing it when encountered is awesome.

Comment: You can try now

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: What has your input?

Comment: the input was a - minus symbol. I wrote the program in .py file and I am running it on the terminal for testing/debugging.